# Spoofing Entire MAC address and hostname automatically on Boot on M1 Macs

Tags: terminal, xcode, mac-address

So I would like to spoof my entire MAC address every time on boot up. I followed [this](https://github.com/sunknudsen/privacy-guides/blob/master/how-to-spoof-mac-address-and-hostname-automatically-at-boot-on-macos/README.md) guide but it only spoofs the last 3 blocks of Mac address. What changes should I make so that the entire MAC address is spoofed and not just the last 3 blocks? And also is it possible to switch rapidly between 'spoofing entire Mac address' and 'spoofing just the last 3 blocks' with simple terminal commands? If so then I need your help.

And I would also like to spoof to one particular fake MAC address which is same every time whenever I copy paste a terminal command how do I go about this?

I found this code online that spoofs the entire MAC address

openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/(..)/\1:/g; s/.$//'

And also would this command given right above give me an infinite permutations of MAC Address or just a few MAC Addresses

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following the guide, you have created a script named `spoof.sh`. In this script, you have the following lines:

```
mac_address_suffix=$(openssl rand -hex 3 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//')
mac_address=$(echo "$mac_address_prefix:$mac_address_suffix" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
```

You can change as follows to use the command, you have indicated you like to use:

```
mac_address_suffix=$(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//')
mac_address=$(echo "$mac_address_suffix" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
```

Note that it is not really a good idea to randomly change all components of your MAC address like that. Some MAC addresses are not valid, or have a special meaning - so you might experience various problems that way from time to time.

Regarding the need to switch "rapidly", you can just make two copies of your `spoof.sh` file. One with the original contents and one with the updated contents - and then you can copy whatever file you want to `spoof.sh` as you see fit.

Regarding the number of permutations: A MAC-address consists of 48-bit (here represented as 6 groups of 2 digit hexadecimal numbers) - so you can never get an "infinite number of permutations". In this case you're just choosing random numbers, so even though it is not infinite, it is still quite a lot. More precisely, you'll be able to get 2^48 permutations (281.474.976.710.656 permutations).

Comment: Those first three blocks only mean that the network interface is made by Apple. All Apple computers have those (or similar blocks identifying Apple). I cannot see how that would affect your personal privacy, since Apple makes millions upon millions of computers.

Comment: Regarding problems: Some MAC addresses are what is known as multicast - they are meant to be used only when you trying to send data that is to be received by multiple computers simultaneously. That is not what you usually want. Similarly there are other addresses that have specific meanings for various topologies. All those “special ones” are distinguished by “something” in those first three blocks. For example multicast is a single bit in the first block.

Comment: The other problems you might see is that you could potentially choose a MAC address that is already in use - although that would require you to have a very big network for that to be a probability worth worrying a lot about.

Comment: After reading your second comment I believe it's wise to stick to that guide and not tamper with the first 3 blocks of a MAC address, and your last comment seems to be an extreme case but why would that be a probability worth worrying a lot about?

Comment: That depends on how those programs are made. It’s generally a bad idea to spoof MAC addresses for such a purpose. Remember that MAC addresses are only visible on your local network. If your are on a home network, I don’t see any reason for spoofing. If you don’t want programs on your own computer knowing your MAC address, use code injection to stop them doing so.